# Google App Engine (Java) web service authentication/authorization/security

Tags: java, web-services, google-app-engine, authentication, rest

I currently have a Google App Engine app consisting of two parts:

A website using old school JSPs
A RESTful service implemented in Jersey

I've been trying to figure out how to shoehorn authentication into the web service but am rather lost since I've never used Spring before, and it sounds like that's the way to go.

Must I use Spring, or can I use Java EE?  Are there any examples of how to accomplish this with Google App Engine?

Also, if I can get a high level description of some best practices for securing web services, that would be cool.

Thanks
Mark

Answer (score 0):

app engine has [built in OAuth support](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/oauth/overview.html), which should do what you want.

Comment: ok. do you mean that you already have an existing login system set up with your own user names, passwords, etc? or do you just not want to use google accounts? If the latter, you might want to reconsider. using google accounts will give you a ton of mature, useful functionality that you probably don't want to reimplement on your own.

Comment: also, if you do want to implement it yourself, OAuth is probably still be a good approach. it's being adopted rapidly as a standard, so there are lots of mature, general purpose client- and server-side libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I recomend you use apache shiro instead of spring because performance  more over if you haven't got experience with spring. [Apache shiro](http://shiro.apache.org/) is a security framework  and it could be integrated with GAE. You also can find a example in [github](https://github.com/cilogi/gaeshiro)how integrate the framework in GAE with Guice library.
Anyway for use Spring in GAE you also can find same best practice on [Google Cloud Platform documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/spring_optimization)